# What is the "Badge" field for in a Tab Bar Item's attributes inspector?

Tags: xcode, uitabbar, xcode-storyboard

I'm familiar with badges, and working with them from code, but the Attributes Inspector for a Tab Bar Item has a *Badge* field. What is this field for?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's for displaying an indicator above the tab bar icon. It's useful for notifying the user that there is new data available on a certain tab.

From the `UITabBarItem` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbaritem):

> Text that is displayed in the upper-right corner of the item with a
>   surrounding red oval.

[image: A screenshot of a tab bar icon with a badge value of 3]

Above is a tab bar item with a `Badge` value of `3` set in the storyboard.

(This value can also be set programmatically with the `badgeValue` property.)

Comment: Hrm, had Xcode behaved right when I tried it, I wouldn't have had to ask the question. Thanks for taking the time to post an answer.

Comment: No problem, the great thing about Stack Overflow is that your question can help lots of other people in the future as well!